# Slow query after adding subquery

Tags: mysql

Running the following works great:

```
SELECT email FROM User WHERE empNum IN (126,513,74)
```

However, this takes a very long to reply (no errors) using:

```
SELECT email FROM table1 WHERE empNum IN (
   SELECT empNum FROM table2 WHERE accomp = 'onhold' GROUP BY empNum
)
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Maybe table2 doesn't have an index on `accomp`?

Comment: If `table2` is large and `accomp` has no index, it's going to be slow.  This can also be done with an inner join.

Comment: @valtron There is no index on accomp. Should it be 'index' or 'fulltext'?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Joins still puzzle me. Could you suggest code?

Comment: @David Everyday there are several new questions asking how to join 2 tables. I suggest you look at one of the previous questions (either in the "Related" column, or using the search function).

Comment: It looks like `accomp` probably holds short strings and would only be queried by exact matches, so a regular index is what you need

Comment: What are the indexes on table1 and table2?

Comment: @didierc table1 - num (unique) & table2 - empNum (unique)  just those 2

Comment: @David didierc's answer below is the correct join (the other is just missing the `DISTINCT`)

Comment: Without an index on `table2`, using a join will still be slow.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Appreciate the `DISTINCT`. I noticed that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that one?

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.email
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 USING(empNum)
WHERE table2.accomp = 'onhold'
```

You should probably make an index on `table2.accomp` if you use that query often enough:

```
CREATE INDEX accomp ON table2 (accomp);
```

or maybe

```
CREATE INDEX accomp ON table2 (empNum,accomp);
```

To perform some crude (but deciding) benchmarks:

1. log in mysql console
2. clear the query cache(*):

   ```
   RESET QUERY CACHE;
   ```
3. run the slow query and write down the timing
4. create an index
5. clear the query cache
6. run the slow query and write down the timing
7. drop the index
8. create the other index
9. clear the cache
10. run the slow query one more time
11. compare the timings and keep the best index (by droping the current one and creating the correct one if necessary)

<sub>(*) You will need the relevant privileges to run that command</sub>

Comment: Is this suggested instead of setting an index?

Comment: The second index wouldn't be helpful in this query.

Comment: I very rarely use this query. However, you've cracked open the door ... to the `index` concept.

Comment: @valtron Why wouldn't it be helpful? Using the query above does result in a quick query with desired results.

Comment: The first index is good; the second not as much: the reason being that with the first one, the index filters out the relevant rows from `table2` directly. The second index needs to scan through `table2`, and for each `empnum` then filter out based on the value of `accomp`

Comment: @valtron By first & second, are you meaning didierc's `CREATE INDEX ...` statements or empNum & accomp??

Comment: you already have an index on empNum, so I guess that the second index would be a bit redundant. I'm leaving it just in case, if the first one doesn't bring enough performance, so that you could try out the second one. I don't know which type of index would be more efficient. I guess that btrees are better when there's ordering concerns (`ORDER BY`), but at any rate the best way to know is to conduct tests.

Comment: Before the testing phase, comes the 'gotta know what to type' phase. :)

Comment: @David The first and second `CREATE INDEX`

Answer (score 1):

I think the join statement you need is:

```
SELECT email FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.empNum=table2.empNum
AND table2.accomp = 'onhold'
```

Comment: Good answer. As noted above, is is better with DISTINCT.